# Python Plugin for XCode

Tags: python, xcode

I'm searching for a Xcode plugin to develop Python applications on Mac OS X platform. Can you give me some links please ? That will be very kind of you.

Cordially, Vynile.

Answer (score 3):

XCode can create Cocoa-Python application projects by default.
Why do you want a plugin?

**EDIT**

It seems Apple removed (since XCode 3.2) the project templates for third-party languages, like Python.
So on a fresh XCode installation, they are not available.

You can still get them from here: http://svn.red-bean.com/pyobjc/trunk/pyobjc/pyobjc-xcode/

The templates needs to be installed in `/Developer/Library/Xcode/Project Templates/`

Comment: Maybe your version of XCode is too old. What version are you using, on which OS version?

Comment: Can you precise a little bit more ? What files should be copied into the *Project templates* folder ? 

Thanks :) !

Comment: The SVN repository has exactly the same structure. So simply copy the 'Project Templates' files into the 'Project Templates' directory. You can do the same with the 'File Templates'.